# What's the worst case scenario if one runs individual queries when pgbouncer has pool_mode=transaction?

Tags: performance, pgbouncer

Let's assume following config for `pgbouncer`:

```
pool_mode=transaction
reset_query=discard all
reset_query_always=0
```

If I have a connection that does

```
begin transaction
...
commit transaction
```

then it's pretty simple because during the transaction is open, pgbouncer will reserve the backend connection for this client connection only.

However, if a client app instead sends

```
select select pg_advisory_lock(123);
begin transaction isolation level serializable
...
commit transaction
select select pg_advisory_unlock(123);
```

**is it possible that the backend connection is switched between queries** so that backend connection #1 acquires the lock, connection #2 executes the transaction and connection #3 tries to unlock the advisory lock and obviously fails?

(The advisory locking would be used as an optimization for high load situations where collisions between serialized transactions cause high CPU load on the backend database server due lots of rolled back transactions. Normally collisions happen seldom enough that serializable transactions result in lower latency than using explicit locking.)

Here's the only related question that I can find:
[How does pgbouncer behave when transaction pooling is enabled and a single statement is issued?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23394272/334451) – however that doesn't answer my problem. Reading the answers suggests that if advisory lock is taken/released when timeout has not been exceeded since previous query the above should work, but I don't know if that can be trusted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this with following pgbouncer config:

```
[pgbouncer]
pool_mode = transaction
server_reset_query = DISCARD ALL
server_check_query = select 1
server_reset_query_always = 0

max_client_conn = 2000
default_pool_size = 1
min_pool_size = 1

reserve_pool_size = 0
reserve_pool_timeout = 5

max_db_connections = 1
```

and two parallel connections to same database through pgbouncer. Following uses P1 ja P2 as identifiers for the queries sent by each process. If one does a simple test such as:

```
P1: set application_name=p1;
P1: select pg_advisory_lock(42);
P2: set application_name=p2;
P1: show application_name;
    p1
P2: select pg_advisory_lock(42);
P2. show application_name;
    p2
```

... **it seems that both connections were able to acquire the same exclusive advisory lock even though they have unique application_name values so each connection should be unique!** In reality, all commands have been sent to postgres using a single connection so this single connection has acquired the advisory lock 42 twice and everything is fine if it releases the same lock later twice (logically once per P1 and P2 connection). This happens because exclusive locks can be taken multiple times by the same owner and must be released equally many times before any other process can acquire the same lock.

As a result, following is also possible:

```
P1: select pg_advisory_lock(42);
P2: select pg_advisory_lock(42);
P1: begin transaction isolation level serializable;
P1: select 1;
P1: commit;
P2: begin transaction isolation level serializable;
P2: select 1;
P2: commit;
P1: select pg_advisory_unlock(42);
P2: select pg_advisory_unlock(42);
```

Imagine multiple queries and database changes instead of `select 1` above.

**Note that both database client applications acquired exclusive lock before doing serializable transaction and things still didn't work correctly.**

Obviously this kind of situation is not possible unless P1 and P2 actually share the same database connection. And normally one would allow more than one parallel database connection through pgbouncer so this kind of code is racy. In practice, it will work until you hit high server load and then you get random failures depending on which query gets executed together with another query from another client.

As a result, it's definitely NOT safe to do any queries outside the transaction if `pool_mode=transaction` is active. The option `server_reset_query_always=1` cannot really fix the problem and should never be used. If you feel that you need `server_reset_query_always=1` you need to use `pool_mode=session` instead or you're risking random data corruption.

In addition, pgbouncer seems to be clever enough to fake *some* connection specific data. For example, when P1 sets its application_name in the first example above and later queries it after P2 has already set its application name on the same connection, the P1 will get the expected result. However, if you monitor the `pg_stat_activity` while this is taking place the only active connection to postgres changes its application_name value each time P1 or P2 sends a query. This makes it *appear* that this kind of mixing is okay with `pool_mode=transaction`.

In the end, setting `application_name` outside the transaction should be safe but any feature actually implemented on the postgres level is not safe. Unless you're *absolutely sure* that pgbouncer can emulate the feature you need, do not emit any query to database connection acquired from pgbouncer in `pool_mode=transaction` except `begin ...`, `commit ...` or `rollback`. Once the transaction is active the connection has been reserved for you and everything works the as with real direct connection to postgres until you do `commit` or `rollback`.

I would really like that pgbouncer would always return an error any time a client tries to do any query outside a transaction if `pool_mode=transaction` has been set. Unfortunately, this is not the reality we live in and pgbouncer clients have to be careful instead.

Comment: I don't quite understand, given this example, why you would say "As a result, it's definitely NOT safe to do any queries outside the transaction if pool_mode=transaction is active."  

I do understand why it's not safe to do `select pg_advisory_lock(42)`.

But why, for example, would it be unsafe to do `select my_column from my_table limit 1` outside of a transaction?

Comment: I meant "any" as in "any possible query" (that is, queries without special restrictions). You can run queries outside a single transaction with `pool_mode=transaction` as long as those queries do not have any side-effects. If the executed query doesn't change or depend on connection state, it's fine to run outside a transaction. However, that includes all queries from *all software* connected to the same `pgbouncer` instance: if a client modifies connection level settings, other clients may receive different response compared to usual response, which may be pretty hard to debug.